# How to alert webmaster if he does not put contact address

Tags: cookies, credentials

i found a session cookie that contains user status with two parameters NO for standard users when altering this to YES you become a Premium user and you can download content restricted to premium users? the problem there is no contact address to send him a message?
any idea ?

Comment: Hmm,  no contract address??  Maybe he doesn't want to be contacted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to get in touch with a website owner then there's a couple of possibilities.

- Some domains might map standard names (e.g. webmaster@[domain], contact@[domain], info@[domain])
- DNS records may well contain a contact name/address.  So running 'whois' will return that info.
- Also IP address whois can return contact information.  So running 'dig [web server addresss]' and then running 'whois' on that IP address might provide more info.

One thing to watch is that some people don't like their security flaws being pointed out to them so you might want to use an e-mail account that doesn't directly tie back to you, in case they decide to get awkward..

Comment: Damn it Rory how many times are you going to edit this? I get 1/2 way through an edit and it's like "This had been edited".

Comment: `support@` and `security@` are also RFC-compliant addresses to send security notices to.

Comment: @Rory Thank you, it is mentioned in whois both admin and technical contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [the whois record](http://who.is/) for the domain. This will give you administrative and technical email addresses and phone numbers which are usually valid, as the domain was registered with them.